# Partial Update a document in ElasticSearch using Java API

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-rest-client

I want to partially update a document in elastic search using java api. My ES mapping looks like :

"mappings": {

```
"DOC_TYPE": {
   "properties": {
        "FieldA": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "FieldB": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "FieldC": {
            "type": "long"
        }
  }
```

}

I want to update the value of FieldA. For the same I am using the following logic :

**NOTE** : map is containing the value to be updated. It is of type <String,Object>

**UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest()
.doc(map, XContentType.JSON);**

**Update.Builder builder = new Update.Builder(update).index("INDEX_NAME").type("DOC_TYPE").id("id");**

**client.execute(builder.build());**

But I am getting error :
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;"}]

I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong as **I have already added doc in my request**.

**NOTE** : I am using JEST client here.
**Is it possible to partially update the document via Jest Client?**

Comment: Which version of ES you are using, now ES supports official java client and Jest is not recommended and not available in latest versions of ES

Comment: Try `updateRequest = new UpdateRequest().index(indexName).type(type).id(id).doc(json);` All of type String

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I am using 6.4

Comment: @Gibbs the suggested method is throwing exception when doc(json) is executed.

Comment: @PiyushKumar curious to know why you are not using JLRC which was released in 6.0 only please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high.html